# What is the symmetry difference between simple-cube and body-centered-cube structures

Tags: crystals

If the lattice types are categorized according to the point group symmetries, then what is the difference, for example, between sc and bcc structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3D there are 7 *lattice systems* which are classes of lattices having the same point group. One of them is the class of cubic lattices. This class contains three different [Bravais lattices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice) which are distinguished by their *translation group*.